# How do I change the cardview color when I select it with long click?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

[image]

How do I change the cardview color after I select it with a long click?

Comment: I tried setting a view with a different color in the selected card position, but it did not work

Comment: Include some code how you got this far,

Comment: Set an onLongClickListener on your cardViews and use cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(yourDesiredColor);